# Can't save record using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My objects will not save no matter what I do they will fetch and get info and make a new record but not update.

This is the code that details with getting existing patient and then modifying the record setting the state then calling save change this is cracking my head the last three hours what is going wrong. I was told you had to change the entity state of an object before it would no if to save but when i try to attach it it says its already attached

```
Appointment _appointment = new Appointment();
int errorCount = 0;

Patient _patient = SourceDal.getPatientByPatientNewId(Convert.ToInt32(txtPatientId.Text));

_patient.SSN = txtSSN.Text;
_patient.FirstName = txtPatientFirstName.Text;
_patient.LastName = txtPatientLastName.Text;
_patient.Middle = txtPatientMiddle.Text;
_patient.AddressOne = txtPatientAddressOne.Text;
_patient.City = txtPatientCity.Text;
_patient.State = txtPatientState.Text;
_patient.ZipCode = txtPatientZip.Text;

_patient.HomePhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;
_patient.WorkPhone = txtPatientWorkPhone.Text;
_patient.CellPhone = txtPatientCellPhone.Text;

if (rBtnHomePhone.Checked == true)
    //   _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;

if (rBtnHomePhone.Checked == true)
    //   _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;

if (rBtnWorkPhone.Checked == true)
    // _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientWorkPhone.Text;

_patient.BirthDate = dtBirthDate.DateTime;
_patient.emailAddress = txtPatientEmail.Text;
_patient.Race =   Convert.ToInt32(dpRace.SelectedValue);
_patient.Ethnicity =Convert.ToInt32(dpEthnicity.SelectedValue);
_patient.Language =  Convert.ToInt32(dpLanguages.SelectedValue);

if (dpGender.Text == "")
{
    dpGender.Focus();
    errorCount = 1;
    lblGenderRequired.Text = "* Gender is required.";
}
else
{
    errorCount = 0;
    lblGenderRequired.Visible = false;
}

_patient.Gender = "M";
_patient.PatientID = txtPatientId.Text;

SourceDal.SourceEntities.Patients.Attach(_patient);
SourceDal.SourceEntities.Patients.Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(_patient, EntityState.Modified);
SourceDal.SourceEntities.SaveChanges();
```

The error I get is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>
> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

**Edit 2**:

Code to show my function `getPaitnetByPatineyNewId`

```
    public Patient getPatientByPatientNewId(int newId)
    {
        Patient patient = new Patient();

        if (newId == -1)
        {
            patient = new Patient();
        }
        else
        {
            patient = SourceEntities.Patients
                                    .Where(w => w.ID == newId)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return patient;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using EF6?

Comment: @yuyangJian EF5

Comment: @yuyangJian project reasons cant upgrade so have to go with it

Comment: @davidbuc your entity is already attached to the context (you're getting it and not removing it, or not using `AsNoTracking`, so EF keeps track of it). That's why you can't attach it.

Comment: @ESG thanks for the quick answer could you provide a solution as to what i might do to solve this .

Comment: @ESG Bascially I am fiinding if they exist as a patient if not create a new record if they already exist update it

Comment: @ESG for if i just fire the save chanages it doesnt get written to db no error messages or nothing back

Comment: @davidbuc Can you post the code for `getPatientByPatientNewId` ?

Comment: @ESG please see edit 2 above mate.

Comment: just guess, add a `no parameter constructor` to `Patient` class, such as `public Patient() {    } `, and use  `Patient patient = new Patient() {  } ;`, try add the bracket

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some issues with proper separation of concerns within your DAL, but for the short solution, you should only add (and not attach) if it's a new entity

```
if (_patent.PatentId == 0)
{
    _patient.PatientID = txtPatientId.Text; // If you're using an identity column, remove this line. I would also strongly suggest not letting the user change this...
    SourceDal.SourceEntities.Patients.Add(_patient);
}
```

Comment: But how do i tell it if its changed as calling save changes is not updating the record ?.

Comment: New entities should be added, not attached. For existing entities, EF tracks all those changes to object properties so you should not have to do anything special, unless change tracking is actively disabled, in which case you have another problem on your hands

Comment: I am using ef5 how would one check that

Comment: It would be the `Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` property (defaults to `true`)

Comment: I keep seeing i have to use this to force entry.State = EntityState.Modified; the state how would i use that in the above thougyh

Comment: I would do an else statement and do that there, but really, you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone else the above scenarios did not work for me so this is what I had to do. I put a flag on my forms isUpdate and check that on the save button then if save call similar to below then if add just call savechanges and its now working thank you for everyone help hope this help someone.

```
public void SaveProviders(Provider _providers)
{
  try
    {


            using (var ctx = new SMBASchedulerEntities(this.Connectionstring))
            {
                ctx.Providers.Add(_providers);
                ctx.Entry(_providers).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }


        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Generally if you want to check your model is valid before sending it to the DB (and throwing errors) you can just call `DbContext.GetValidationErrors()` instead.